# SQL query multiple values in just one cell

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I am kinda new to sql. Just wanna know if this is possible via sql:

**Table**: (Multiple values are in just 1 cell.)

| COLUMN 1 | COLUMN 2 |
| --- | --- |
| "2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03" | "User A, User B, User C" |

**Needed Output**:

| COLUMN 1 | COLUMN 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | User A |
| 2023-01-02 | User A |
| 2023-01-03 | User A |
| 2023-01-01 | User B |
| 2023-01-02 | User B |
| 2023-01-03 | User B |
| 2023-01-01 | User C |
| 2023-01-02 | User C |
| 2023-01-03 | User C |

Basically, each date from the row is assigned to all users in that same row. Any help or tip will be appreciated.

Thank you!
[Screenshot of data/required table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuNJI.png)

I have no idea yet on how to go around this

Comment: Your proposal would break the classical Codd idea of relational database design. So it can be done but would most likely (much) less easy going as when you'd do ["normalization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? Please tag yours.

Comment: @JonasMetzler i'm using postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `string_to_array` function to get all parts of a string as elements of an array, then use the `unnest` function on that array to get the desired result, check the following:

```
select col1,
  unnest(string_to_array(replace(replace(COLUMN2,'"',''),', ',','), ',')) as col2
from 
(
  select unnest(string_to_array(replace(replace(COLUMN1,'"',''),', ',','), ',')) as col1
         , COLUMN2
  from table_name
) T
order by col1, col2
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fbwryd7f)

Answer (score 1):

We can use a combination of `STRING_TO_ARRAY` with `UNNEST` and `LATERAL JOIN` here:

```
SELECT col1.column1, col2.column2
FROM
(SELECT UNNEST(
  STRING_TO_ARRAY(column1,',')
) AS column1 FROM test) col1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(SELECT UNNEST(
  STRING_TO_ARRAY(column2,',')
) AS column2 FROM test) col2
ON true
ORDER BY col2.column2, col1.column1;
```

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rmfPr2CF)

`STRING_TO_ARRAY` will split the different dates and the different users into separate items.

`UNNEST` will write those items in separate rows.

`LATERAL JOIN` will put the three dates together with the three users (or of course less/more, depending on your data) and so creates the nine rows shown in your question. It works similar to the `CROSS APPLY` approach which will do on a SQL Server DB.

The `ORDER BY` clause just creates the same order as shown in your question, we can remove it if not required. The question doesn't really tell us if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because implementation details van change on different DBMS's, here is an example of how to do it in MySQL (8.0+):

```
WITH column1 as (
   SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1,',',x),',',-1)) as Value
   FROM test
   CROSS JOIN (select 1 as x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) x
   WHERE x <= LENGTH(Column1)-LENGTH(REPLACE(Column1,',',''))+1
  ),
  column2 as (
   SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column2,',',x),',',-1)) as Value
   FROM test
   CROSS JOIN (select 1 as x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) x
   WHERE x <= LENGTH(Column2)-LENGTH(REPLACE(Column2,',',''))+1
  )
SELECT * 
FROM column1, column2;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/X0B0Vfpf)

NOTE:

- The CROSS JOIN, with only 4 values should be expanded when more than 4 items exist.
- There is not data type connected to the values that are fetched. This implementation does not *know* that "2023-01-08" is, sorry CAN BE, a date. It just sticks to strings.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server this can be done using string_split

```
select x.value as date_val,y.value as user_val
 from test a
CROSS APPLY string_split(Column1,',')x
CROSS APPLY string_split(Column2,',')y
order by y.value,x.value

date_val    user_val
2023-01-01  User A
2023-01-02  User A
2023-01-03  User A
2023-01-03  User B
2023-01-02  User B
2023-01-01  User B
2023-01-01  User C
2023-01-02  User C
2023-01-03  User C
```

db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/YNJWDPBq

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can do it as follows :

```
WITH dates as ( 
  select TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_date, ',', 1)) AS 'dates'
  from _table
  union 
  select TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_date, ',', 2), ',', -1)) AS 'dates'
  from _table
  union
  select TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_date, ',', -1)) AS 'dates'
  from _table
),
users as
  ( select TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user, ',', 1)) AS 'users'
  from _table
  union 
  select TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user, ',', 2), ',', -1)) AS 'users'
  from _table
  union
  select TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user, ',', -1)) AS 'users'
  from _table
)
select *
from dates, users
order by dates, users;
```

check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/_oGix9PD